# triple des implementation hex input

Tags: java, encryption, tripledes

Doing triple DES with the code :

```
public class TripleDES {

    private static sun.misc.BASE64Decoder decoder = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder();
    private static sun.misc.BASE64Encoder encoder = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            try {
                Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Installing SunJCE provider.");
                Provider sunjce = new com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE();
                Security.addProvider(sunjce);
            }

            File keyFile = new File("D:/3DES/keygen.txt");

            /*
             * writeKey(generateKey(),keyFile);
             * System.out.println("After writing to file");
             */

            SecretKey rKey = readKey(keyFile);
            System.out.println("Secret key :" + rKey);
            String encryptedMssg = encrypt(rKey, "afda");
            System.out.println("Encrypted mssg :" + encryptedMssg);

            String decryptedMssg = decrypt(rKey, encryptedMssg);
            System.out.println("Decrypted mssg :" + decryptedMssg);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            System.err.println("Usage: java " + TripleDES.class.getName()
                    + " -d|-e|-g <keyfile>");
        }
    }

    public static SecretKey generateKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyGenerator keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DESede");
        System.out.println(keygen.generateKey());
        return keygen.generateKey();
    }

    public static void writeKey(SecretKey key, File f) throws IOException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        SecretKeyFactory keyfactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
        DESedeKeySpec keyspec = (DESedeKeySpec) keyfactory.getKeySpec(key,
                DESedeKeySpec.class);
        byte[] rawkey = keyspec.getKey();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
        out.write(rawkey);
        out.close();
    }

    public static SecretKey readKey(File f) throws IOException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException,
            InvalidKeySpecException {
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        byte[] rawkey = new byte[(int) f.length()];
        in.readFully(rawkey);
        in.close();
        DESedeKeySpec keyspec = new DESedeKeySpec(rawkey);
        SecretKeyFactory keyfactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
        SecretKey key = keyfactory.generateSecret(keyspec);

        return key;
    }

    public static SecretKey readKey(byte[] rawkey) throws IOException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException,
            InvalidKeySpecException {
        // DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        // byte[] rawkey = new byte[(int)f.length()];
        // in.readFully(rawkey);
        // in.close();
        DESedeKeySpec keyspec = new DESedeKeySpec(rawkey);
        SecretKeyFactory keyfactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
        SecretKey key = keyfactory.generateSecret(keyspec);

        return key;
    }

    public static String encrypt(SecretKey key, String clearData)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException,
            NoSuchPaddingException, IOException, Exception {
        System.out.println("inside encrypt");
        System.out.println("KEYYYYY::" + key);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] cleartext = clearData.getBytes("ASCII");
        byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(cleartext);

        return encoder.encode(ciphertext);
    }

    public static String decrypt(SecretKey key, String encryptedData)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, IOException,
            IllegalBlockSizeException, NoSuchPaddingException,
            BadPaddingException, Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] dec = decoder.decodeBuffer(encryptedData);
        byte[] clearbytes = cipher.doFinal(dec);

        return new String(clearbytes, "ASCII");
    }


}
```

With this code I shouldn't be doing encryption then decryption and then encryption again?
It is generating the encrypted string but it is not matching with the online des calculators  where is the problem area.

what is the problem area?

Answer (score 1):

The encryption algorithm `"DESede"` is using key C for encryption, key B for decryption and key A for encryption. These keys are taken from the data provided to `DESedeKeySpec`. So `DESedeKeySpec` should contain the keys C, B and A concatenated: 3 * 8 bytes = 24 bytes.

Newer Java versions also support DES EDE keys of 16 bytes. In that case encryption, decryption and encryption is performed by key A for encryption, key B for decryption and A for encryption again. This is often called an DES ABA key.

In other words, DESede indeed uses three keys *inside the algorithm* itself. You don't have to program this yourself, and your code seems to execute fine.

Comment: Note that having the code running does not necessarily mean it is secure - and as you seem to use DESede and ECB encoding it probably isn't.